# IdentityServer3 - Recommend Authentication with a Custom Grant and javascript OIDC Client

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect

I have a web site using an out of the box Identity Server 3/javascript OIDC client that require a username/password authentication request to lock down the pages at the web site. This is working.

I now need to be able to have a customer tell us which user was authenticated on their platform and map that into a user/identity on our platform and pass that information to the existing web site without having to prompt for a username/password.

I am currently using RequestCustomGrant to generate an access_token and I am able to map that data to a user/identity in our system and generate a valid access_token with a Custom Validator.

I then attempted to craft a URL with a hash fragment similar to https://xxxx/#access_token=eyJ0e.....&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=ps-api

The problem that I am running into is the oidc client seems to want both an access_token and an id_token along with some state information. If I also craft an id_token I get an error

oidc-client.min.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) Error: No state in response
    at e.t.processSigninResponse (oidc-client.min.js:3

Is it possible with the oidc-client and its UserManager to just take an access token and then validate that, call back to the userinfo_endpoint to craft an id_token and persist that in the user store, or is this a bad approach?

I am wondering if custom grants are the wrong approach and what the preferred approach is to handle a situation where the original authentication mechanism is using some custom approach and we would like to validate that request and generate a new token that can be used by our web applications and API which all expect JWT tokens.